What are effective strategies to verify if my personal R package setup is interacting correctly?
When looking at how dependencies are traced in R packages then we can often see something like package A depends on >= some version of package B. In practice, package A can, however, not foresee which changes will be made to package B in future. Thus, it is possible for me to install a setup that appears to be technically sound and only starts creating problems when the code is actually executed. The example below already implies one type of solution. i.e. run all the unit tests written by the developers and check for failures.
How can I technically address this scenario and prevent creating such a system setup?
The specific example revolves around dplyr 1.1.0 introducing changes that break something in version 2.1.0 of janitor::adorn_percentages(). This is addressed and fixed in version 2.2.0 of janitor (see NEWS).
# R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

remotes::install_version("dplyr", version = "1.0.10", dependencies = FALSE, upgrade = "never")
remotes::install_version("janitor", version = "2.1.0", dependencies = FALSE, upgrade = "never")

# R session needs to be restarted here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

# show versions
packageVersion("dplyr")
# > [1] ‘1.0.10’
packageVersion("janitor") # Imports (among others) dplyr (>= 1.0.0)
# > [1] ‘2.1.0’

# get and extract source archive to run tests
download.file(url = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/janitor/janitor_2.1.0.tar.gz",
              destfile = "janitor_2.1.0.tar.gz")
system("mkdir janitor_2.1.0; tar -zxf janitor_2.1.0.tar.gz -C janitor_2.1.0")

# run tests
devtools::test("janitor_2.1.0/janitor/")
# > [ FAIL 0 | WARN 1 | SKIP 1 | PASS 629 ]

# update dplyr from "1.0.10" to "1.1.0"
remotes::install_version("dplyr", version = "1.1.0", dependencies = FALSE, upgrade = "never")

# R session needs to be restarted here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

packageVersion("dplyr")
# > [1] ‘1.1.0’

# run tests
devtools::test("janitor_2.1.0/janitor/")
# > [ FAIL 1 | WARN 1 | SKIP 1 | PASS 619 ]

remotes::install_version("janitor", version = "2.2.0", dependencies = FALSE, upgrade = "never")
download.file(url = "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/janitor_2.2.0.tar.gz",
              destfile = "janitor_2.2.0.tar.gz")
system("mkdir janitor_2.2.0; tar -zxf janitor_2.2.0.tar.gz -C janitor_2.2.0")

# R session needs to be restarted here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

packageVersion("janitor")
# > [1] ‘2.2.0’

# run tests
devtools::test("janitor_2.2.0/janitor/")
# > [ FAIL 0 | WARN 10 | SKIP 2 | PASS 780 ]


You could use something like renv to lock packages at certain versions that you've tested. But there's not really a perfect, generic way to make sure packages will never break with version mismatches. There could always be problems that aren't caught when running packages tests as well because they were not known yet.

FWIW: Using the smallest technically valid version of a package for the personal dependency tree seems to mitigate this to some extent.
